# Aggregated Computed property not getting updated in ember

Tags: ember.js

Aggregated Computed property not getting updated in ember

```
Val.set('arr',[]);
Val.set('arr',[{val:1},],[{val:2}],[{val:3}],[{val:4}]);
Val.reopen({
    total:function(){
           var array=this.get('arr');
           var total=0;
           for(i=0;i<array.length;i++)
           {
               total=total+array[i].val
           }
           return total;
    }.property('arr.@each'),
});
```

**this thing works for the first time but property observers never get called second time whenever array elements are updated.**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to observe the properties from the objects in the array then you are missing here something:

```
    ...
    }.property('arr.@each')
```

try to change your code to this

```
    ...
    }.property('arr.@each.val')
```

otherwise ember will only notice changes on the array itself (removing/adding elements) and not changes to the properties of those objects inside the array.

*not part of the answer, but as a inspiration ,you could do your total method more conveniently like so, using the built-in [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method:*

```
 Val.reopen({
   total:function(){
     var total = this.get('arr').reduce(function(a, b) {
       return a.val + b.val;
     });
     return total;
   }
 });
```

hope it helps